# Does iOS 10 now allow apps to access the content of iMessage messages?

Tags: ios, ios10

Wondering whether the intro of iMessage apps means they opened up that capability

Answer (score 0):

No.

An iMessage app has access to the specific custom/interactive messages created with that app, whether received or sent, but not to other message content. See [iMessage + Apps](https://developer.apple.com/imessage/) on the Apple Developer site for details, docs, and sample code.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunate for your app idea, perhaps. Fortunate for users who don't want third party apps reading all their conversations.